# when download project from angular docs and running ng serve -o project definition could not be found

Tags: angular, angular8

I am using Angular CLI: 8.1.2 and want to start learning it from [Angular IO Tutorial](https://angular.io/start#getting-started-with-angular-your-first-app)
and when i download the code and doing `ng serve -o`

It shows the error:

```
The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
```

I've tried to update it but is not working because I am using the newer angular cli.

Angular File Project Project That I Have been downloaded from https://angular.io/start#getting-started-with-angular-your-first-app:

!File Project
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h_ompEiWsNJ8O5n-xVf2y8Ap2e0GVlNi/view?usp=sharing)

My Angular CLI Version:

!Angular CLI
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/18a-4yMrRFMcIv1cTHvZUf6RW79egOUVY/view?usp=sharing)

I expected chrome browser pop up and showing my web app.

Comment: on where file project ? @ElasticCode

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/angular/xeordkpxxyg i download it from here and click download project below fork icon @ElasticCode

Comment: In command line navigate to project folder and run `npm install` then `ng serve -o`

Comment: Refer this comment https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12215#issuecomment-433593036

Comment: do you have facebook? what you told me isnt working and have same error message maybe we can move our chat through facebook ? @ElasticCode

Comment: It seems to be error of angular/cli version and try to use ```ng update @angular/cli``` and look at my answer below.

Comment: did you install Nodejs?

Comment: of couse i did @ElasticCode please read the question and see images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer for this question for all new angular 8 learner 
is to copy ng new  to your stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the folder in question.

So e.g. if you created your app like this:

```
ng new my-first-app
```

Now you need to first:

```
cd my-first-app
```

Then you can run

```
ng serve
```

Or

```
npm start
```

It will work.

Comment: i am doing download from https://angular.io/start#getting-started-with-angular-your-first-app i dont want create new one ~_~" @Zlatko

Comment: From there or from the linked StackBlitz?

Comment: from stackblitz.com/angular/xeordkpxxyg and i download it below fork icon and do ng serve

Comment: did you enter the project directory before you ran it?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer may be here.
https://www.djamware.com/post/5bca67d780aca7466989441f/angular-7-tutorial-building-crud-web-application

`npm install -g @angular/cli`
`ng new angular-new`
`cd angular-new`
`ng serve`

If any problem try this.
`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`
and check your `npm -v` and `node -v`